# Infinispan value as List of objects

Tags: list, dictionary, caching, infinispan

I'd like ask question about values stored in the map for Infinispan cache. I saw many simple examples where key is string and value is some object. Is it possible to create the map where key is string and values contains list of some objects? Is there any limitation in creating values of map which are used as cache?
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store anything in both keys and values, though for clustered caches these objects must be serializable or externalizable.

Note that clustered caches actually store copy of the object, therefore if you do

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
cache.put("key", list);
list.add("foo");
System.out.println(map.get("key"));
```

it will print out only `[]`.